# Как в mono вызвать библиотеку?

Tags: c#, mono

В общем установил **mono**

всё работает ,
но вот библиотеку "перекинуть" как то не получается

вот код :

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    Graphics g;
    private void Draw()
    {
        g = CreateGraphics();
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black,10,10,200,100);
        g.Dispose();
    }
    private void FormMain_Paint(object sender,PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Draw();
    }
}
```

вот результат :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что я делаю не так ??** (библиотеку предварительно перетащил в папку )

---

вот измененый код :

```
using System; 
using System.Draw; 

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    Graphics g;
    private void Draw()
    {
        g = CreateGraphics();
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black,10,10,200,100);
        g.Dispose();
    }
    private void FormMain_Paint(object sender,PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Draw();
    }
}
```

вот результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если это весь код, который содержит ваш файл, то вы не указали using - директивы для системных типов, о чем вам намекает компилятор

Comment: я не знаю, как в mono именовать типы принято, но это `FormMain` сильно режет глаза. что значит "основа формы"? `MainForm` выглядит более читаемо

Comment: @AndreiKhotko добавил

Comment: @return добавил

Comment: @timob256 что вы добавили)

Comment: Вы не указали все используемые пространства имён. Например, `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: Зачем мучаться? Почему бы не установить какую-нибудь IDE?

Comment: Из того, что я вижу, **минимум** того, чего вам не хватает : 1) using-директив для типов Form (`System.Windows.Forms`), Graphics(`System.Drawing`, а не Draw); 
2) импорта необходимых dll в команде `csc` (как минимум, на `System.Windows.Forms.dll`) 3) реализаций методов `CreateGraphics()` и `Draw()`, если они, конечно, не определены в другом файле через `partial`-механизм. Вам нужно внимательно это все исправить, и это только то, что я сразу заметил.

Comment: А вообще, человек выше правильно вам задает вопрос. Почему вы хотите пройти такой сложный путь? Вы же работаете в операционной системе Windows, где есть GUI, а не на какой-то CentOS. Пользуйтесь IDE :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Спасибо за советы они мне очень помогли.**

Благодаря советам я смог найти ответ .

Так же отвечу почему не пользуюсь IDE, у меня старый компьютер с 32 битной системой, для его нет  современных IDE  в основном IDE 2010 годов выглядят они убого, а также требуют большого нажимания сотни чекбоксов и ползунков (также не хочется тратить время на заранее устаревшую и не поддерживаемую технологию).

По этому мне легче работать с командной строкой.

вот ответ правда не причёсанный :

вот код :

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 
 // класс окна
class MyForm:Form{
    // ссылка на объект для рисования
    Pen p;
    // ссылка на объект графического контекста
    Graphics g;
    // конструктор
    public MyForm():base(){
        // размеры окна 
        this.Width=325;
        this.Height=380;
        // окно фиксированных размеров
        this.FormBorderStyle=FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
        // заголовок окна
        this.Text=" чух чух";
        // объект метки
        Label lbl=new Label();
        // размеры метки
        lbl.Width=300;
        lbl.Height=30;
        // положение метки
        lbl.Location=new Point(5,5);
        // рамка для метки 
        lbl.BorderStyle=BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        // шрифт для метки
        lbl.Font=new Font("Arial",10,FontStyle.Bold);
        // способ выравнимвания текста в метке
        lbl.TextAlign=ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        // добавление метки в коно
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
        // объект панели
        Panel pnl=new Panel();
        // размеры панели
        pnl.Width=lbl.Width;
        pnl.Height=300;
        // положение панели
        pnl.Top=lbl.Bottom+5;
        pnl.Left=lbl.Left;
        // рамка для панели
        pnl.BorderStyle=BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        // цвет панели
        pnl.BackColor=Color.Yellow;
        // вид курсора над панелью 
        pnl.Cursor=Cursors.Hand;
        // оъект для рисования
        p=new Pen(Color.Blue,3);
        // объект графического контекста для панели
        g=pnl.CreateGraphics();
        // обработчик события связанного с движением курсора над областью панели 
        pnl.MouseMove+=(obj,ea)=>{
            // перерисовка панели
            pnl.Refresh();
            // текст для метки 
            lbl.Text="Gorizontal: "+ea.X;
            lbl.Text+="  ";
            lbl.Text+="Vertikal: "+ea.Y;
            // Отображение линий
            g.DrawLine(p,new Point(0,ea.Y),new Point(pnl.ClientSize.Width,ea.Y));
            g.DrawLine(p,new Point(ea.X,0),new Point(ea.X,pnl.ClientSize.Height));
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black,10,10,200,100);
        };
        // Обрабочик события, связанного с перемещением курсора за приделы панели
        pnl.MouseLeave+=(obj,ae)=>{
            //текст для метки
            lbl.Text="";
            // перерисовка панели
            pnl.Refresh();
        };
        // добавление панели в окно
        this.Controls.Add(pnl);
    }
    
    // диструктор 
    ~MyForm(){
        // освобождение ресурсов, задействованных для рисования 
        g.Dispose();
        p.Dispose();
    }
}

// главный класс 
class CursorDemo{
    // Атрибут использования однопоточной программы
    [STAThread]
    // Главный метод
        static void Main(){
        // отображение окна
            Application.Run(new MyForm());
        }
}
```

вот результат :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чесно, это лютое извращение. Б.у. комьютер тянущий 64 битную систему и вижуалку на ней - это значительно дешевле чем тратить время на подобные костыли. Это долларов 100 за системник, максимум 200. Это не экономия, это обесценивание своего времени.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 встанет на 32-битную ось, хотя я бы посоветовал поменять систему на 64-битную, как минимум Win 7 со всеми обновлениями. Не думаю, что у вас железо из 90-х годов, для которого не существует 64-битных драйверов. Ставлю рубль, что всё даже быстрее заработает. Если полноценная Visual Studio будет сильно тормозить, поставьте и попробуйте Visual Studio Code.